# Why do I get different output from hexdump compared to xxd?

Tags: hexdump

Why does `hexdump` seem to miss out parts of the file, while `xxd` does not? The file is 32 bytes. So `xxd` output is correct.

```
$ xxd test.bin
0000000: 8888 8888 8888 8888 8888 8888 8888 8888  ................
0000010: 8888 8888 8888 8888 8888 8888 8888 8888  ................
$ hexdump -n32 -x test.bin
0000000    8888    8888    8888    8888    8888    8888    8888    8888
*
0000020
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you didn't add the `-v` option to hexdump.

> **-v** Cause hexdump to display all input data.  Without the -v option, any number of groups of output lines, which would be identical to the immediately preceding group of output lines (except for the input offsets), are replaced with a line comprised of a single asterisk.

Therefore you need:

```
$ hexdump  -n32 -xv test.bin
0000000    8888    8888    8888    8888    8888    8888    8888    
0000010    8888    8888    8888    8888    8888    8888    8888    
0000020
```